# how to query by date offset in Parse with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I want to set a constraint on a Parse query, that takes a birthday ( date), and only gathers results which are within 10 years.

So if the date is something like (1954-01-10 07:00:00 +0000)
then I want to get all records from 1944 to 1964.

Is there some way to do this using Parse query code?

Or,
do I have to obtain the date, then use swift code to offset it by 10 years, then write something like this

```
let currentUserBirthday = PFUser.currentUser()?.objectForKey("birthday")!

// set date 10 years greater and lower than currentUserBirthday
let datePlus10 =   // add 10 years to date
let dateMinus10 =  // subtract 10 years from date

dailyFourQuery?.whereKey("birthday", greaterThanOrEqualTo: datePlus10)
dailyFourQuery?.whereKey("birthday", lessThanOrEqualTo: dateMinus10)
```

edit: hey guys, i solved this by getting the age from the date, then adding or subtracting the integer offset from that number, 
then using NSCalendar and creating components with modified values.
Thanks for all the help.

```
let currentUserBirthdayNSDate = currentUserBirthday as! NSDate

let dateComponents = calendar.components([NSCalendarUnit.Day, NSCalendarUnit.Month, NSCalendarUnit.Year, NSCalendarUnit.WeekOfYear, NSCalendarUnit.Hour, NSCalendarUnit.Minute, NSCalendarUnit.Second, NSCalendarUnit.Nanosecond], fromDate: currentUserBirthdayNSDate)

let componentsPlus10 = NSDateComponents()
componentsPlus10.day = dateComponents.day
componentsPlus10.month = dateComponents.month
componentsPlus10.year = dateComponents.year + 10
componentsPlus10.hour = dateComponents.hour
componentsPlus10.minute = dateComponents.minute
```

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to calculate the two dates in Swift and user `greater/lessThanEqualTo:` in the query. Parse does not have any special methods for date queries as far as I know.

Comment: I know Parse has something called Cloud Code, which may be the solution to your problem. Besides that, I do not believe their API has that functionality you are asking for.

Comment: alright... thanks guys.
I'm reading http://www.appcoda.com/nsdate/   and it seems to have good solutions for modifying the date.

Comment: https://github.com/MatthewYork/DateTools has a lot of very handy date manipulation add-ons.

Comment: I have done same thing but it is in objective c. if u know it then plz tell me.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to [SwiftDate](https://github.com/malcommac/SwiftDate)

```
// Reference date is: Thu, 19 Nov 2015 19:00:00 UTC (1447959600 from 1970)
let refDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 1447959600)

// Remember: all parameters are optional; in this example we have ignored minutes and seconds
let newDate = refDate.add(years: 1, months: 2, days: 1, hours: 2)
// newdate is 2017-01-21 14:00:00 +0000

// This is equivalent to
let newDate2 = refDate + 1.years + 2.months + 1.days + 2.hours
```

do you want this?